# How can i convert curl to urlfetch

Tags: urlfetch

How can i convert this to urlfetch I have not found that good documentation

```
$url = "http://www.smscountry.com/SMSCwebservice.asp";
$message = urlencode($message);
$ch = curl_init();
if (!$ch) {die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");
}
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "User=$user&passwd=$password&mobilenumber=$mobilenumbers&message=$message&sid=$senderid&mtype=$messagetype&DR=$DReports");
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curlresponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thota, have you found a solution to this ?

Comment: have you looked at this solution ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114206/replacing-curl-with-urlfetch-in-php

Comment: I'll be interested to see how the above gets converted to urlfetch

Comment: No Axil i haven't found

Comment: try following this, posted something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775207/convert-php-curl-to-gae-urlfetch-for-itunes-inapp-verifyreceipt

Comment: Thota, can you create a chat room, since you have reputation over 100, lets discuss how to solve it.